# Why SVG adds some space inside it?

Tags: svg

I'm quite new to SVG and trying to generate an object which will consist of several small svgs put in one line.
I have a problem getting rid of spaces which svg adds with it. What I want that the elements will touch each other.

I created a small example: http://jsfiddle.net/PFWBC/1/

```
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     viewBox="0 0 65 65"  width="50" height="50">
   <path d="M10,10   l50,0  0,50  -50,0  0,-50"
      style="stroke: #000000; fill:none;" />
</svg>
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     viewBox="0 0 65 65"  width="50" height="50">
   <path d="M10,10   l50,0  0,50  -50,0  0,-50"
      style="stroke: #000000; fill:none;" />
</svg>
```

There are two squares here. When you inspect the elements 'path' you will see that it doesn't add any additional space, however, svg tag does.

I tried to change width/height/viewBox in a way that there is no additional space between the 'path' object and 'svg', however, didn't manage to do it, marging/padding also didn't help. Although, I can get rid of the empty space on the right and bottom side, the left and top side still remains...

I found similar questions, but they were about the 100%, which is not my case.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that you're drawing a path which isn't at the edge of the viewBox makes it look worse but the padding is actually caused by the whitespace between `</svg>` and `<svg>`.

In html if you put whitespace between things it gets rendered. The problem is demonstrated more clearly if you replace the whitespace with something you can see e.g.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     viewBox="0 0 65 65"  width="50" height="50">
   <path d="M0,0   l65,0  0,65  -65,0  0,-65"
      style="stroke: #000000; fill:none;" />
</svg>Text<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     viewBox="0 0 65 65"  width="50" height="50">
   <path d="M0,0   l65,0  0,65  -65,0  0,-65"
      style="stroke: #000000; fill:none;" />
</svg>
```

And the solution. Don't add the whitespace in the first place...

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     viewBox="0 0 65 65"  width="50" height="50">
   <path d="M0,0   l65,0  0,65  -65,0  0,-65"
      style="stroke: #000000; fill:none;" />
</svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     viewBox="0 0 65 65"  width="50" height="50">
   <path d="M0,0   l65,0  0,65  -65,0  0,-65"
      style="stroke: #000000; fill:none;" />
</svg>
```

Comment: you are right my biggest problem is with selecting a correct viewBox, the space between blocks was not really a problem.

Answer (score 0):

xml:space is used to handle whitespace only text nodes. The white space comes from whitespace characters, such as tabs, line breaks, or carriage returns, which are located between tags to provide formatting. Removing the "preserve" is equivalent to changing it to "default", which either collapses or replaces the whitespace characters depending on the XML processor. There is a related question with a more detailed explanation.

Comment: xml:space only affects SVG `<text>`, `<tspan>`, `<tref>` and `<textPath>` nodes and the question doesn't have any of those.

Comment: dude easy i am new at this